# Preventing state reset when app moves from background to foreground

Tags: ios, swiftui, nsnotificationcenter, observableobject

I'm working on an iOS app that shows a sheet when a user taps on a notification. The issue arises when the app is brought from the background to the foreground upon tapping a notification. Despite setting a `@Published` property `showReminderDetail` to `true` to present a sheet with more information, it gets overridden and resets to `false` due to the initialization logic in my `@main` class, negating the state change.

Here's the sequence of events as logged by my console:

> Current state of showReminderDetail: false
> Notification received
> Handling notification for reminder ID: E6BDC19C-17F0-4945-96AE-772A4DAA36B9
> Notification received for reminder with ID: E6F0-4945-96AE-772A4DAA36B9
> selectedReminderID is now: Optional(E6BDC19C-17F0-4945-96AE-772A4DAA36B9)
> showReminderDetail set to: true
> Current state of showReminderDetail: false

Here is a simplified version of my relevant app logic:

```swift
class AppLogic: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var showReminderDetail = false
    @Published var selectedReminderID: UUID? = nil
    // Other properties and initializers

    func handleNotificationResponse(with reminderID: UUID) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.selectedReminderID = reminderID
            self.showReminderDetail = true
        }
    }
    // Additional methods
}

extension AppLogic: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Notification handling logic
    }
}
```

and my content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appLogic: AppLogic

    var body: some View {
        // ContentView structure
        .sheet(isPresented: $appLogic.showReminderDetail) {
            // Sheet content
        }
    }
}
```

and my @main:

```swift
@main
struct Conditional_Reminder_AppApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    
    // Initialize AppLogic with the ReminderStorage instance
    @StateObject var appLogic: AppLogic
    
    init() {
         let reminderStorage = ReminderStorage(context: persistenceController.container.viewContext)
         _appLogic = StateObject(wrappedValue: AppLogic(reminderStorage: reminderStorage))
     }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
                .environmentObject(appLogic)
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is how my `@main` class initializes the `AppLogic` object or possibly with how state restoration is handled when the app transitions from background to foreground. However, I've no clue.

How can I maintain the `showReminderDetail` state as `true` when the app is brought to the foreground, allowing the sheet to be presented as intended?

I tried handling state as `UserDefaults` instead of an observable object, but that didn't work either. I'm expecting "Current state of showReminderDetail: true" after tapping a notification and seeing a sheet.

Comment: That `init` is non standard, try removing that